# xslt: embed xml and access it

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Let's say I have this XML file:

```
<ErrorCodes>
<ErrorCode = "1" value = "ABC"/>
<ErrorCode = "2" value = "DEF"/>
</ErrorCodes>
```

Can I add this as a variable in my XSLT file? (I can't save just the XML as a file and reference it in my XSLT). The XML has to be placed inline on my XSLT file.

Is it possible to use XPATH to access my ErrorCodes XML and assign my XSLT variable based on the ErrorCode that I receive as input?

Comment: This isn't an XML file. The ErrorCode elements are not well-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "Yes, you can"

You can define your variable like so (There is no really need for the parent `ErrorCodes` here)

```
<xsl:variable name="errorCodes">
    <ErrorCode code="1" value="ABC"/>
    <ErrorCode code="2" value="DEF"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then you can access it like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="$errorCodes/ErrorCode[@code='2']/@value" />
```

Alternatively, define it like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="errorCodes" as="node()*">
    <ErrorCode code="1" value="ABC"/>
    <ErrorCode code="2" value="DEF"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then the expression simplifies to this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$errorCodes[@code='2']/@value" />
```

You could also access it using an `xsl:key`. For example...

```
<xsl:key name="errorCodes" match="ErrorCode" use="@code" />

<xsl:variable name="errorCodes">
  <ErrorCode code="1" value="ABC"/>
  <ErrorCode code="2" value="DEF"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="key('errorCodes', '2', $errorCodes)/@value" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The caveat is that this assumes XSLT 2.0. With XSLT 1.0, a variable holding XML fragments is called a "result tree fragment" and you need the xx:node-set() extension function to make it queryable.